# Univocity - how to parse 3(n) lines as one row(bean)

Tags: java, univocity

I am evaluating Univocity parser for one of my project, Fixed width flat file format makes one record(Bean) from three detail recs (e.g., starts with AA, BB, CC) - would this file parseable using Univocity?
I can use `recordEndsOnNewline` to continue reading and add some custom conversions, but is there any out of box `ParserSettings`?

```
AA1234 data
BBmore data
CCsome more data row 1 ended
AA5678 data
BBmore data
CCsome more data row 2 ended
```

update:

may be use: `setLineSeparator("\nAA");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of the library here. First you need to define the field positions. As you want to parse values that occur in multiple lines you must set `recordEndsOnNewLine` to `false`, so you are in the right track.

It's easier to "see" where each record starts and ends if you join the lines that form a single record:

```
String input = "" +
    "AA1234 data\nBBmore data\nCCsome more data row 1 ended\n" +
    "AA5678 data\nBBmore data\nCCsome more data row 2 ended";
```

Given the example you provided, the following field configuration can be created (I assumed you don't want the "AA", "BB" and "CC" strings):

```
FixedWidthFields fields = new FixedWidthFields();
fields
        .addField("a1", 2, 6)
        .addField("a2", 7, 11)
        .addField("b1", 14, 23)
        .addField("c1", 26, 40)
        .addField("c2", 41, 52);
```

And you can parse your input with this:

```
FixedWidthParserSettings settings = new FixedWidthParserSettings(fields);
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
settings.setRecordEndsOnNewline(false);

FixedWidthParser parser = new FixedWidthParser(settings);

List<String[]> rows = parser.parseAll(new StringReader(input));
for (String[] row : rows) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

This will give you the correct output:

```
[1234, data, more data, some more data, row 1 ended]
[5678, data, more data, some more data, row 2 ended]
```

Now that we know where each field starts and ends, we can define your java bean:

```
public static class Bean {
    @FixedWidth(from = 2, to = 6)
    @Parsed
    int a1;

    @FixedWidth(from = 7, to = 11)
    @Parsed
    String a2;

    @FixedWidth(from = 14, to = 23)
    @Parsed
    String b1;

    @FixedWidth(from = 26, to = 40)
    @Parsed
    String c1;

    @FixedWidth(from = 41, to = 52)
    @Parsed
    String c2;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bean{" +
                "a1=" + a1 +
                ", a2='" + a2 + '\'' +
                ", b1='" + b1 + '\'' +
                ", c1='" + c1 + '\'' +
                ", c2='" + c2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

With that ready, parsing the input becomes simple as that:

```
FixedWidthParserSettings settings = new FixedWidthParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
settings.setRecordEndsOnNewline(false);
settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(false); // This one is important as your input has no headers.

FixedWidthRoutines routines = new FixedWidthRoutines(settings);
for(Bean bean : routines.parseAll(Bean.class, new StringReader(input))){
    System.out.println(bean);
}
```

Which will print the beans to the output like that:

```
Bean{a1=1234, a2='data', b1='more data', c1='some more data', c2='row 1 ended'}
Bean{a1=5678, a2='data', b1='more data', c1='some more data', c2='row 2 ended'}
```

Hope this helps